# HTML5 Google Chrome - Datepicker - Delete Cross

Tags: html, google-chrome

**Problem with Google Chrome since some day**!

[image]

I have a little problem. I use an input-field with type="date".
Since some day it appers a cross after filling the inputform.
This is only at Chrome.
How can I suppress the displaying of these cross?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this answer can help you

as it will deal with the deleting the cross in chrome browser

[How to remove the blue cross on datetime-local HTML input in Chrome 27?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688417/how-to-remove-the-blue-cross-on-datetime-local-html-input-in-chrome-27)

Comment: input::-webkit-outer-spin-button, /* Removes arrows */
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button, /* Removes arrows */
input::-webkit-clear-button { /* Removes blue cross */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

try to add `required` attribute.